# Using bool to let users define strategy settings pine

Tags: boolean, pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have just picked up coding this week and trying to make a strategy out of an indicator our organisation uses. I want to let the user pick the type of inputs that make up the strategy for extensive backtesting. I want to do this with Bool inputs (true or false). E.g. so users can select to use either a crossover, close above MA or both for a entry trigger.

```
Entry1 = input.bool(defval=false, title="MA crossover", group='4HTrend')
Entry2 = input.bool(defval=false, title="MA Above?", group='4HTrend')
Entry3 = input.bool(defval=false, title="price close?", group='4HTrend')

Bull = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 10), ta.sma(close, 5))
TLEntryTrigger2 = ta.sma(close, 10) > ta.sma(close, 20)
Long = close > ta.sma(close, 50)
plot(ta.sma(close, 10)) 
plot(ta.sma(close, 5)) 
plot(ta.sma(close, 20)) 
plot(ta.sma(close, 50), color=color.new(color.white, 0)) 


var bool longConditionEntry = na  
if Entry1 and Entry2 and Entry3 
    longConditionEntry := Bull and TLEntryTrigger2 and Long 
else if Entry1 and Entry2 
    longConditionEntry := Bull and TLEntryTrigger2 
else if Entry1 
    longConditionEntry := Bull  
else if Entry2 
    longConditionEntry := TLEntryTrigger2 
else if Entry3 
    longConditionEntry := Long
else if Entry3 and Entry2 
    longConditionEntry := Long and TLEntryTrigger2 
else if Entry3 and Entry1 
    longConditionEntry := Bull and Long 



plotshape(longConditionEntry, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0), style=shape.cross, size=size.normal, location=location.belowbar)
```

I have tried above code and it works good except when it seems to overwrite some values(?) E.g. when I tick Entry 2 and 3 to be true it still plots the cross on closes below the 50 ma. After some more testing it seems to work fine if Entry1/2/3 are all ticked ánd just Entry3 is ticked. All other combinations with Entry3 it seems to ignore Entry3

[Screenshot of erroneous bars.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syC0E.png) See 11 April 2022, 10 and 11 'o clock in the morning and 13 april 2022, 9 and 10 'o clock in the morning for the erroneous bars

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with your complete chart visible (ticker id, exchange, timeframe and date)? So we can find that exact bar on our end and investigate your issue better.

Comment: Just edited. Thanks for the tip! Just for clarity the ticker is CADCHF, timeframe is 1H and the echange is OANDA. Time and dates are included in the post.

Comment: Fixed it for now! added `and not` statements which seems to fix the issue!